# can overuse in Macros hurt performance?

Tags: c++, c, performance

I have a very long code, which is being called millions of time,
I have noticed that if I change all the macros into inline functions the code runs a lot faster.

Can you explain why this is? Aren't macros only a text replacement? As opposed to inline functions which can be a call to a function?

Comment: Do you have a multiple evaluation bug?

Comment: Something like `#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))`, which evaluates its arguments multiple times.

Comment: i don't understand the bug here. can you explain

Comment: macros are just text replacement. To see what your compiler is doing with them, compile with the `-E` flag, such as `g++ -E file.cpp`

Comment: `MAX(expensivecall(), otherexpensivecall())` will perform one of those expensive calls twice. With multiple macros, the bug gets even worse.

Comment: If using C++ do not use macros. Inline functions would be better

Comment: random thought: Compiler can better reason about variable lifetime in inline functions?

Comment: i get it so if i just replace the text i have no idea what are X or Y and sometimes it will take long time to compute them, and then in order to give back a result we will compute it back again.

Comment: Consider functions X have side effects!

Comment: @EdHeal thanks as i said i'm changing them from Macros to inline functions i was just wondering why does the code run faster?

Comment: @Androidy - The compiler understands the semantics of the language. The preprocessor does not. Hence the compiler can have a better bash at optimisation

Comment: @Androidy: Well, if the macro defines local variables, they will remain in scope for the function the macro is used in. If you instead call an inline function, normal scoping rules apply, and the local variables disappear when they are no longer needed. A modern compiler might get this right on its own, but that's speculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A macro is a text sustitution and will as such generally produce more executable code. Every time you call a macro, code is inserted (well, not necessarily, the macro could be empty... but in principle).
Inline functions, on the other hand, *may* work the same as macros, but they might also not be inlined at all.

In general, the `inline` keyword is rather a weak hint than a requirement anyway, compilers will nowadays judiciously inline functions (or will abstain from doing so) based on heuristics, mostly the number of pseudo-instructions.

Inline functions may thus cause the compiler to *not inline* the function at all, or inline it a couple of times and then call it non-inined in addition.
Surprisingly, not inlining may actually be faster than inlining, since it reduces overall code size and thus the number of cache and TLB misses.

Answer (score 7):

This will depend on the particular macro and function call that you are using. A particular macro can actually compile to a longer set of operations than the inline function. It is often better not to use a macro for certain processes. The inline function will allow the compiler to type check and optimize the various processes. Macros will be subject to a number of errors and can actually cause various inefficiencies (such as by having to move variables in and out of storage).

In any case, since you actually see this happening in your code, you can tell that the compiler is able to optimize your inline code rather than blindly put in the text expansion.

Note that a google search 'macros vs inline' shows a number of discussions of this.

Comment: I read most of them.  They do not give good example for macros performance going bad.  Just stuff like wrong outputs and why inline is better

Comment: @Gilad Personally, I would set the preprocessor options and the compiler options to expand an area of your code to see what the macro and inline versions are doing different. I might also tell it to generate the assembly for a small (or even minimal) chunk of code to see what the optimization is doing. I would also try different levels of optimization to see what is going on.  You might also show actual macro and inline code as part of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from forcing inlining, macros can also be detrimental to speed if they are not carefully written not to evaluate their arguments twice. Take for example this little function-like macro and its inline function equivalent:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))

inline long square(long x) { return x*x; }
```

Now, when you call them with a variable `square(foo)`, they are equivalent. The macro vesion expands to `((foo)*(foo))`, which is one multiplication just like the function if it's inlined.

However, if you call them with `square(expensiveComputation(foo))`, the result of the macro is, that `expensiveComputation()` is called twice. The inline function, in contrast, behaves like any function: its argument is evaluated once before the body of the function is executed.

Of course, you could write the macro using the gnu extension of compound statements (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html for documentation on this) to avoid double evaluation like this:

```
#define square(x) ({ \
    long square_temp_variable = (x); \
    square_temp_variable*square_temp_variable; \
})
```

But this is a lot of hassle, and it makes the code unportable. So, better stick with inline functions.

Comment: Not only that but the creation of the local variable square_temp_variable within the macro range can cause processing slowdown. It might be minimal but over millions of times, it could add up

Comment: @sabbahillel That is not true, there is no overhead of defining a new local variable compared to an inlined function call. Remember that a function call will create variables for all the function parameters. And even if the compiler inlines the call, the resulting code must act *as if these variables were created*. Copy elision is allowed, of course, but so it is if you create a local variable in a macro.

Answer (score 3):

at general it is a good advise to replace function style macros by inline functions wherever this is possible.

not only you ged rit of some nasty traps `a = MIN(i++, 50)` for example you also gain typesafety and as already stated in some comments you avoid multiple evaluation of arguements, that may have very bad influence on performance.

Comment: I don't really feel like this answers the question very adequately. The OP wants to know **why** macros can result in worse performance, but you've given him various other (not relevant) arguments against using macros, and a very brief mention of multiple evaluation of arguments (without any elaboration), which was already better dealt with in a comment. The answer could be improved by taking out the irrelevant stuff and expanding upon the performance explanations.